# .NET treeview sort alphabetical by node type

Tags: .net, sorting, treeview

I have a treeview that implements 2 types of items, folders and items.
When I sort them I want the items to appear below the folders

like

```
folder a
   subfolder a
   subitem z
folder b
item a
item b
```

How can I modify my sort routines?

```
Public Class ascsorter
Implements Collections.IComparer
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) _
    As Integer Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare
    Dim tx As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(x, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Dim ty As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(y, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Return -String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)
End Function
End Class

Public Class descsorter
Implements Collections.IComparer
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) _
    As Integer Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare
    Dim tx As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(x, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Dim ty As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(y, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Return String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)
End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to distinguish between which nodes are folders and which nodes are items.  The `Tag` property can be used for this.  In this example, I used "a" for folders and "b" for items:

Sample unsorted nodes with Tags:

```
Dim nodeA As New TreeNode("folder a") With {.Tag = "a"}
nodeA.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("subitem z") With {.Tag = "b"})
nodeA.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("subfolder a") With {.Tag = "a"})
nodeA.ExpandAll()

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("folder b") With {.Tag = "a"})
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(nodeA)

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("item b") With {.Tag = "b"})
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode("item a") With {.Tag = "b"})

TreeView1.TreeViewNodeSorter = New ascsorter
TreeView1.Sort()
```

And the updated Comparer which sorts the Tag property first:

```
Public Class ascsorter
  Implements Collections.IComparer

  Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) _
      As Integer Implements Collections.IComparer.Compare

    Dim tx As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(x, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Dim ty As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(y, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)

    If Not tx.Tag.Equals(ty.Tag) Then
      Return String.Compare(tx.Tag, ty.Tag)
    End If

    Return String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)
  End Function
End Class
```

Note: No error checking if the Tag property was set or not.

Comment: yes i use `Tag` property for a ton of stuff like this. tx so much, it would've taken me ages to figure out this simple solution